# Redirection oddities with conditions and querystring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here's essentially what I'm trying to do:

- If the URL a visitor requests points to a file or directory, show that file
- Else, redirect back to the index.php file

The .htaccess file below is working great; the only issue I'm facing is that if the URL a visitor requests is a PHP file with $_GET parameters, they are taken to the index.php file instead of the file they should be going to. Any ideas on how I can fix that?

```
# Prevent "Index Of" pages
Options -Indexes 

# Rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, go to it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache normally cuts off the query string. To append it, the qsappend flag (QSA) should be included in all your rewriteRule lines, like this:

```
# Prevent "Index Of" pages
Options -Indexes 

# Rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# If requested resource exists as a file, do not rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

// EDIT: You are explicitly rewriting existing files to themselves. Just don't do that, but bail out if your URL hits an existing file. (code above edited.)

Comment: What's wrong with rewriting existing files? This is a very common way to enforce single-point access in a web-based system.

Comment: Ah, but he's not redirecting in those cases. OK.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it in general, but in this case writing just an opposite condition gives exactly the same result, and takes one rewrite less. (Eventually getting rid of the problem TS is having.)

Comment: And now that I've thought through what we've discussed, and written it into a comprehensive answer, it strikes me that that's exactly what you already wrote 11 minutes ago. D'oh. :( Still, I think that there's value in my explanation, so I'll leave my answer up.

Comment: I tried using exactly what you posted above, but the results were exactly the same as my original .htaccess file.

Comment: Is it only failing on a www. prefix, or is it failing on any request?

Comment: For some reason, when I try with www, it goes to domain.com/403.shtml. Without www, it shows the URL that was requested, but the index.php page comes up

Comment: First, try changing `.*` into `.+` in the first rewriteCond. (see above) That should at least fix the 403.

Comment: Great, www redirection is working perfectly now. Using GET parameters still isn't working out that well though

Comment: So, let's get one thing straight. Is the query string to `index.php` not specified? Or are you trying to access another file, which doesn't seem to get GET variables?

Comment: @S.K. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2537/discussion-between-pelle-ten-cate-and-s-k)

Comment: Ah, I see what was wrong, it was something with my PHP script apparently. I created a test one right now (http://skoshy.com/page/hello/?hi=2) that just print_r()'s the $_GET variable and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, go to it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
```

Aren't you potentially looking for a file like "somepath.php?querystring" on the filesystem, by doing this? I think that `$1` includes the querystring.

So these conditions fail, and you fall through to the final rewrite rule. The user gets sent to `index.php`, but they lose the giveaway querystring because you're not using [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

---

#### Solution

Try:

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,L]
```

Don't forget `[QSA]` to keep the querystring, if present.

You should add it to the final rule, too:

```
# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

---

#### Suggestion

Are you sure you want to do no-op rewrites? That's a bit odd.

How about negating the logic and combining those two rules? Like so:

```
# If requested resource doesn't exist as a file or directory, rewrite to /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You are ORring the two negative conditions, while they should be ANDed! (Since they're negative...) Otherwise it will ALWAYS rewrite. (A given string is always either not a file or not a directory, it can't be both.)

Comment: I tried out both suggestions, but neither of them did the trick (everything acted exactly the same as before). What does %{REQUEST_FILENAME} contain exactly? If the URL requested was http://example.com/page.php?q=hi, would it contain http://example.com/page.php?

Comment: No, the question mark will not be appended. In a normal request, it resolves into the name of an existing file. Get rid of the [OR], and if it still doesn't work, tell us exactly what you are trying or review your apache configuration. (I just tested this, works fine here.)

Comment: I got rid of the [OR] (i.e. I used exactly what you posted in your answer after your edit, Pelle) and it's still not redirecting properly. I'm requesting http://example.com/page/?src=something, and I get redirected to my index.php page. Going simply to http://example.com/page/ works fine, though.

Comment: @Pelle: Yea I noticed that and edited it out about a minute before your comment :P

Answer (score -1):

[Mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Search for `QSA`

Comment: Tried replacing [L] with [QSA,L], but same behavior happened. I think I'd need to change something within the actualy RewriteConds, not the RewriteRules